# ¿Cómo puedo definir variable para consulta (C# .Net)?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Tengo que realizar una consulta en c# .NET, a la hora de realizar la consulta de un if en una variable group y después utilizar un .GroupBy. Como podría definir esta variable group para que sea utilizada tanto en el if como en el selectGroup?

```
var where = _plapsaContext.Payments.AsQueryable();
var tables = _plapsaContext.Payments;
if (paymenyEvolutionQuery.ContractCode.HasValue)
        {
            where = where.Where(x => x.CollectedContractCode == paymenyEvolutionQuery.ContractCode.Value);
        }

var group = ???

if (paymenyEvolutionQuery.DetailByContract)
        {
            group = where.GroupBy(x => new
            {
                PaymentDate = x.PaymentDate.Month,
                ContactCode = x.CollectedContractCode,
                OwnersAssociationCode = x.CollectedOwnersAssociationCode
            });
        }
        else
        {
            group = where.GroupBy(x => new
            {
                PaymentDate = x.PaymentDate.Month,
                ContactCode = x.CollectedContractCode
            });
        }

var selectGroup = group.Select(g => new PaymentEvolutionSummary
        {
            Month = g.Select(x => x.PaymentDate.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
            ContractCode = g.Key.ContactCode,
            OwnersAssociationCode = g.Key.OwnersAssociationCode,
            AmountTotal = g.Sum(x => x.NetAmount),
            ExpensesAverage = g.Average(x => x.NetAmount),
            PaymentsTotal = g.Count(),
            FunctionalUnits = g.Select(x => x.FunctionalUnitCode).Distinct().Count()
        });
```

Espero su respuesta. Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Entiendo que no sabes como inicializar la variable no? Si es el caso, simplemente podrías setear inicialmente la variable en `null`

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Es buena idea. Solo que al hacerlo, me aparece: "No se puede asignar <<NULL>> a una variable con tipo implícito."

Comment: Rayos! Mira, [este articulo](https://www.variablenotfound.com/2009/09/inicializar-null-propiedades-sin-tipo.html), explica el error y te entrega una posible solución.

Comment: Dale, muchas gracias! @PauloUrbanoRivera

Comment: Me parece que es un IQueryable :)

Comment: @GianfrancoGrigera comentanos si te sirvió y cuál fue la solución!

Comment: Con respeto a eso, no me sirvió. Ya que no sabía que tipo darle. Me ayudó bastante el comentario de abajo! Gracias por tu ayuda igualmente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba usando el **operador ternario** **?:**

```
var group = (paymenyEvolutionQuery.DetailByContract) ?
             where.GroupBy(x => new
             {
                PaymentDate = x.PaymentDate.Month,
                ContactCode = x.CollectedContractCode,
                OwnersAssociationCode = x.CollectedOwnersAssociationCode
             }) : 
             where.GroupBy(x => new
             {
                PaymentDate = x.PaymentDate.Month,
                ContactCode = x.CollectedContractCode
             });
```

El **operador ternario** funciona como la condicional **if/else**.

Si esta condición se cumple:

```
(paymenyEvolutionQuery.DetailByContract)
```

entonces se ejecutará lo que sigue al símbolo **?** y **group** tendrá dicho valor, en caso de no cumplirse se ejecutará lo que sigue al símbolo **:**, y **group** tendrá dicho valor.

Usar el **operador ternario** reduce código y hace que este quede más legible, puedes investigar más en **Internet** si lo deseas.

Comment: Entendí que el problema del OP es como inicializar la variable, no por la condición @Japv :O

Comment: Aqui tambien la estas inicializando, en base a una condicion, se inicializa de una forma o de otra.

Comment: Tienes razón!! +1 :D

Comment: Perfecto! Esto me sirvió a la perfección! Muchas gracias por su respuesta!